Increase speed of XML parsing in Python
I have to parse XML data in the ten to hundred TB range (yes, I know). You can imagine each XML document as being a collection of records and the goal is to select a small subset of the fields from each record.
I have been using the iterparse function in the lxml library and following the advice from the author. My code looks similar to the version that runs in 0.97s except with more complicated logic. However, my parser is not really as fast as I would like it to be and I am looking for any advice, libraries and techniques that can speed up the parsing -- no matter how small.
The only caveat is that the advice should be for Python or for libraries that have Python bindings.

I think a compiled program will be faster than python.  If you give me a sample I can try PS script to see if faster.  For huge xml files it is recommended using XmlReader which doesn't give out of memory errors like many other libraries.

XML is inherently slow. For fast parsing, binary alternative are often needed since there is AFAIK no way to make XML parsing fast in sequential. The best you can do is using multiple threads. Some modules are a bit faster than other so choosing a good one may help but be aware that allocations (in the same process) tend not to scale so it is better if the libraries are designed for parallel processing. if you can compute each XML independently in multiple processes without IPC, this is even better.

If some parts of your XML are very simple to parse and rather massive, then you can parse such nodes yourself. It is less flexible, but a specialized parser writing in native code (or Cython) and doing less check can be significantly faster, especially if you use SIMD instruction for that (pretty hard) and avoid allocating nodes on the heap (not easy regarding what you parse). For example, parsing arrays of integers where each integer is in an XML node can be much faster which this solution. The resulting array can be stored in a contiguous array (eg. Cython vector, Numpy array).

Alternatively, you can just try PyPy blindly. It may be significantly faster in sequential with the right library assuming the bottleneck is the interpreters or allocations (PyPy is a JIT compiler with a GC).

@jdweng unfortunately this is an ML project and the entire codebase is in python. this is the only bottleneck so far in the project and I don't want to fragment the code unless there is no other way

You said "libraries and techniques that can speed up the parsing' which didn't say that python was a requirement.

@JérômeRichard I can compute each XML independently without IPC and that is what I do. I'm not really aware of any library in the XML space that does parallel, binary parsing. If there is something close to SIMDjson for XML it would be perfect but I've never found any.
I never considered PyPy! Thanks. I will try it out and post back. I have considered creating specialized parsers but only as a last resort since the subset of fields we parse can change week to week.

@jdweng my bad! sorry! i meant libraries or techniques in python or libraries that have bindings to python (like LXML which I believe is a wrapper over libxml2)

Creating a wrapper add another method so there is an overhead of calling the method.

How long is it currently taking? 100Tb is 10^14 bytes, it would be very ambitious to try to get parsing faster than 10 instructions per byte, Under perfect conditions you might execute 10^11 instructions per second, so that would be 10^4 seconds or 3 hours. That's a pretty ambitious target, how far short of it are you?

Honestly, if your current code is already parallel using multiple processes and the XML structure frequently changes, then I think the best solution is clearly to move to binary files. 3 TB of XML is already really not normal and using a faster library will certainly not give you a huge boost (as opposed to binary files). IMHO XML is pretty hard to parse with SIMD units, so while there are some SIMD-accelerated XML library (IDK for Python), the benefit is rather small in practice (AFAIK always <2x and often <1.5x).

@JérômeRichard Thanks for your advice. I am petitioning the team that produces this data to provide some binary serialized data. I am leaning towards messagepack / protobufs but I'm open to any recommendations.

@MichaelKay off the top of my head I think parsing 50GB takes around 15-20 minutes but this also includes the time taken to write parquet files using polars. I will get back to you with concrete benchmarks.

@wildcat That's in line with my experience: about 2Gb per minute for streamed XSLT 3.0 processing, so I would regard anything over 10Gb per minute as outstandingly good, but possibly achievable by very careful low-level tuning. 50Gb per minute (or 100Tb in 3 hours) feels like a theoretical limit.
